# Différent de d'habitude

Tags: grammaire, expressions

J'entends parmi certains franco-canadiens de telles expressions que "différent de d'habitude" et "parlons de d'autre chose". Le redoublement du "de" est redondant et donc donne un air dodu, disons, aux phrases, alors j'ai fait une petite recherche sur [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams).

Le deuxième exemple n'est certainement pas standard : l'expression devrait être "parlons d'autre chose", tout simplement. Soit.

Cependant, pour le premier, Ngrams m'indique qu'effectivement, "différent de d'habitude" existe depuis à peu près l'année 2000 et devient de plus en plus courant. Voilà la langue en évolution. Par contre, "différent d'habitude" n'existe pas du tout, contrairement à mes attentes.

Alors voici la question : comment exprime-t-on "différent de d'habitude" autrement? J'imagine que le concept a quand même dû exister au vingtième siècle...

Answer (score 1):

On peut dire "différent que d'habitude" pour éviter cette tournure de phrase.  L'enjeu c'est que *différent que [x]* n'est pas toujours de bon usage et on préfère dire *différent de [x]*.

Puisque *d'habitude* est une locution adverbiale figée et *une habitude* est un nom, l'expression  "différent d'habitude" pourrait signifier une différence de comportement.  Donc il est facile d'insérer un "de" pléonastique, surtout si l'on cherche le contraire de "comme d'habitude".

Sinon, je suggère "pas comme d'habitude" ou "de façon inhabituelle."

De plus-t-en plus curieux !

Comment: J'ai pourtant vérifié "différent que d'habitude" auprès de Ngrams pendant mes recherches, et il paraît que cette tournure de phrase est encore plus rare. Effectivement, c'est curieux !

Comment: Attention, Ngrams ne reconnaît pas toujours la différence des formes verbales (diffèrent) de l'adjectif.

Answer (score 0):

On pourrait dire

> ...pas comme d'habitude.

> ...différent de ce dont j'avais l'habitude / de ce à quoi j'étais habitué.

Mais "différent de d'habitude" est tout à fait correct, aussi inélégant soit-il à l'écrit (à l'oral, ça passe mieux je trouve...)

Comment: À l'oral, ça passe peut-être mieux parce que c'est généralement prononcé *différent d'd'habitude*.