# "Différent que" vs "différent de"

Tags: expressions, usage, de, que

According to the site [http://chouxdesiam.canalblog.com/archives/2010/02/27/17057870.html#:~:text=D'apr%C3%A8s%20le%20Hanse%2DBlampain,sont%20bien%20diff%C3%A9rentes%20des%20v%C3%B4tres](http://chouxdesiam.canalblog.com/archives/2010/02/27/17057870.html#:%7E:text=D%27apr%C3%A8s%20le%20Hanse%2DBlampain,sont%20bien%20diff%C3%A9rentes%20des%20v%C3%B4tres).

one must use **différent de** and not **différent que**. Nevertheless, I am quite sure that I've heard and seen written the latter turn several times.

Are there any cases where the latter turn should be preferred? Or should we stuck always with the former one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used to compare two things, *de* is expected.

> A est **différent de** B.

Using *que* here would be very colloquial.

I have nevertheless found a printed example of such usage:

> *Elle se concentre sur ce qui est **différent que** d'habitude.* Hildegard Aman-Habacht, *Ménopause 3/2019*, (certainly translated from German, both the author and the editor being Austrians).

It is likely a translator attempt to avoid the repetition of *de* is *[...] qui est [différent de d'habitude](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43267/diff%C3%A9rent-de-dhabitude).* I would have written *qui est différent de ce qui se passe d'habitude*.

When there is no comparison, *différent que* can be heard, for example in a *ne .. que* turn:

> *L'exemple que voici n'est **différent que** parce que l'adjectif est pourvu ici de l'article.* Guy de Poerck

> *C’est **différent que** pour les joueurs qui évoluent à l’étranger et ne reviennent ici que pour l’équipe nationale.* [Kilian Mbappé](https://www.ouest-france.fr/sport/football/kylian-mbappe/psg-kylian-mbappe-au-sujet-des-critiques-bien-sur-que-ca-fatigue-a7438154-92ab-11eb-acd5-9322c40ace42)

Comment: Thanks a lot! L'exemple que voici n'est différent que parce que l'adjectif est pourvu ici de l'article.  That's a weird sentence (for me at least:-)!). Could I ask a new question about its structure?

Comment: Surprisingly (for me always:-)!) deepl's translation is to the point and makes sense: The following example is different only because the adjective here has the article.

Comment: Justement en français du point de vue grammatical c'est *que* qui introduit le deuxième élément de la comparaison (et il y a *plus* ou *moins* devant le premier). Quand tu dis « A est différent de B » tu fais une comparaison d'**ordre lexical**.   Et c'est pour ça que *que* ne convient/drait pas après *différent* ou *semblable * ou *pareil* ou *supérieur*, etc... . Ceci est très peu étudié en français, même l'AF est muette sur le sujet (!?!?)  (alors qu'en anglais la littérature abonde sur *different from* vs *different than*).

Comment: La tendance à dire « différent que » est de plus en plus grande, même dans la langue écrite journalistique, peut-être verra-t-on une évolution, mais pour l'instant *différent de* est considéré comme une faute de français que la majorité des enseignants sanctionnent. Après, moi, je ne juge pas, du moment qu'on se comprend... Ah oui, il est possible de dire *différent à*,  voir Littré par ex.

Comment: @Laure j'imagine que tu voulais dire *différent que* est considéré comme une faute de français. Je n'ai pas vraiment remarqué de *différent que* de la part de journalistes. Je ferai plus attention...

Comment: oui différent que est considéré comme une faute!  Pas que les journalistes d'ailleurs, c'est fréquent à l'écrit...